# How to Join Array of struct on table1 with normal column of table 2 in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, join, struct, google-bigquery

[Tabel1 and Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udhUJ.png)

```
select p.id,q.description
from table1 p 
join table2 q 
on q.control_number 
in unnest(p.results.control_number)
```

When I process this I'm getting the below error:

> Cannot access field control_number on a value with type
> ARRAY<STRUCT<control_number string,...., …>>

I have also tried un-nesting after the table like:

```
select p.id,q.f.description 
from table1 p,Unnest(finder) f 
join table2 q 
  on q.control_number in unnest(p.f.results.control_number)
```

But this also did not work.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option

```
select p.id,q.description
from table1 p, table2 q 
where q.control_number in (select control_number from p.finder)
```

Comment: HI Mikhail,

Thank you for taking effort to help me. But when I run the query, I'm getting all descriptions in one row only instead  against each control_number and Id. Could you please suggest me possible fix

This is query I used,
select p.finder, q.description
from table1 p, table2 q 
where q.control_number in (select control_number from p.finder)

Comment: you got exactly what you asked! in your next question - please make sure to provide all details - sample input, expected output. etc. check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Meantime i consider your initial question is fully answered  :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in standard SQL:

```
with table1 as (
    select '1' id, array[struct('a1' as control_number)] finder
    UNION ALL 
    select '2' id, array[struct('a2' as control_number)] finder
    UNION ALL 
    select '3' id, array[struct('a3' as control_number)] finder     
),
table2 as (
    select 'description for a1' description, 'a1' control_number 
    UNION ALL
    select 'description for a2' description, 'a2' control_number 
)
select p.id,q.description 
from table1 p, unnest(p.finder) f join table2 q on q.control_number = f.control_number;
```

`WITH` clause is used to simulate data in your tables.

Comment: Thanks for taking effort to help me. but when I try to run this query, it running for more than 5 mins but no results yet. I tried stopping it and re-running but did not improve the performance. Is there any change to make?